# How do I sign up for LotW as a new ham?

Tags: lotw

I installed `tqsl` to get started with LotW, but the first screen requires me to enter "Date of the first QSO you made or will make using this callsign". I haven't made any yet, and I don't know the future, so what do I put in this field? Is it simply used as the certificate start-of-validity date, so I enter today's date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any day after the day your license was issued will work fine. What it's really trying to tell you is that your certificate can't be used to sign any QSO made *before* its start date.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting, start of validity. Thanks.